# Is there a way to create a Test Case in TFS without associating it to a Test Suite?

Tags: tfs, mtm

I'm trying to find a way to add test cases to TFS without the need to first associate it to a Test Suite or Test plan.  I envision it as just a backlog test case that can be associated to a Suite/Plan as needed for future test efforts.  Is that possible using Web Access or the Test Manager application?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Test Case by adding a new item under the "Tested Cases" section of a user story/PBI. It will create the test case with a link of the type "tested by".

Answer (score 0):

To create a test case work item, you can go to Team Explorer -> Work Item -> New Work Item -> Test Case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to tag a test case to any Test Plan or Suite. Basically Test case is a TFS Work item. So you can do it by following 'Team Explorer -> Work Item -> New Work Item -> Test Case.' or If you are accessing MTM via web Interface, Go to Work>WorkItems>New>Test Case